# Java - GridBagLayout Button Alignment

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I've been getting into building my UI's using GridBagLayout and so far, I really like it. It's much more flexible than all the other layout out there that I've seen.

I have ran into one issue, however. I have an app UI that I'm building and I have all the components laid out in the grid. However, for some reason, when I override the preferred size of the JPanel, my buttons that are underneath it shift over as well.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SignaturePadUI {
    private JPanel panelMain;
    private JPanel panelSignature;
    private JLabel labelAppTitle;
    private JLabel labelTotal;
    private JLabel labelSignHere;
    private JButton buttonCancel;
    private JButton buttonAccept;

    public SignaturePadUI() {
        panelMain = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        labelAppTitle = new JLabel("Signature-O-Matic");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        panelMain.add(labelAppTitle, c);

        labelTotal = new JLabel("Total: $114.98");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        panelMain.add(labelTotal, c);

        panelSignature = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(375, 75);
            }
        };
        panelSignature.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        //c.weightx = 1.0;
        //c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        panelMain.add(panelSignature, c);

        labelSignHere = new JLabel("Sign here.");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 30, 5);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        panelMain.add(labelSignHere, c);

        buttonCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        panelMain.add(buttonCancel, c);

        buttonAccept = new JButton("Accept");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        panelMain.add(buttonAccept, c);
    }

    public JPanel getPanelMain() {
        return panelMain;
    }
}
```

[image: My Current UI]

My current UI and code is listed above. The buttons *were* centered until I made the JPanel wider. Now they are shifted over to the left and I have no way of getting them back to the center. Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: This has a lot to do with how `GridBagLayout` calculates its column widths, a component which spans multiple columns does not affect the size of the individual column, so the column in which the `Cancel` button resides is actually only wide enough to fit that button, since nothing else actually "resides" within that column. The column for the `Accept` button is also setup the same way, because it's actually the only thing that resides in that column - I know, it's confusing, but that's the way it works

Comment: Solution - Place both the buttons in a single `JPanel` and place that panel into the `GridBagLayout` - you may find that you don't actually needs the column spanning after that

Comment: WOW! That is kind of crazy...and good to know. Thanks you! @MadProgrammer